Collections of items given restraints on parity
I have this question: 12 flowers are bought from a shop which has unlimited stocks of red, pink, black, white, and yellow flowers (indistinguishable apart from colour). How many different collections of flowers can be bought if:
a. in total?
b. in which every colour is either used an even number of times or not at all?
c. in which every colour is either used an odd number of times or not at all?
For part (a) this is just ${16\choose 4}$ using the 'stars and bars' argument.
For part (b), we are looking for $$x_1+\cdots+x_5=12$$ where each $x_i$ is even. Hence if we set $y_i=\frac{x_i}{2}$: $$y_1+\cdots+y_5=6$$ to which the number of ways is ${10\choose 4}=210$.
I am very unsure how to do part (c). I have tried looking at generating functions but I get $(1+x+x^3+x^5+\cdots)^5$ which isn't a geometric series. I have tried doing something similar as in part (b) such as doubling the numbers (setting $y_i=2x_i$), but it hasn't helped. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Three people have given their time  to help you with their effort. You are relatively new to this forum, if answers that serve your purpose are posted, it is expected that you should accept one of them by giving a tick, it also closes the question.

(c): The generating function for the number of solutions in non-negative integers to
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=r$$
where each $x_i$ is either $0$ or odd is
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= (1 + x +x^3 +x^5 + \dots)^5 \\
&= (1 + x(1+x^2+x^4+\dots))^5 \\
&= \left( 1 + \frac{x}{1-x^2} \right)^5 \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} \left( \frac{x}{1-x^2} \right)^i \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} x^i (1-x^2)^{-i} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} x^i \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{i+j-1}{j} x^{2j}
\end{align}$$
where we have used the Binomial Theorem for negative exponents in the last step. So the number of solutions with $r=12$ is
$$[x^{12}]f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^6 \binom{5}{12-2j} \binom{12-2j+j-1}{j} = \boxed{235}$$

I can't immediately see a clever method, but if you have computational assistance, using the g.f. you can find the coefficient of $x^{12} \;in\; (1+x+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9+x^{11})^5$
to get an answer of $235$ for part $(c)$

Over the night, the subconscious worked !
Non-zero$\;$ odd $\;$ entries must occur in either $2$ or $4$ cells to produce the  even number, $12$
Putting $x_i= 2y_i+1$,
either $\sum_{i=1}^2 \;2y_i =10 \implies \sum_{1=1}^2\; y_i=5$
or $\sum_{i=1}^4 \;2y_i= 8 \implies \sum_{i=1}^4\; y_i=4$
Taking into account that when filled cells are two, the cells can be filled in $\binom52$ ways, and when four,, in $\binom54$ ways
answer $= \binom61\binom52 + \binom73\binom54 = 60+175 = \color{blue}{235}$

There’s always the brute-force method. What are the partitions of 12 of which each part is odd, and which of those have at most 5 parts? There are only eight: $11+1$, $9+3$, $9+1+1+1$, $7+5$, $7+3+1+1$, $5+5+1+1$, $5+3+3+1$, and $3+3+3+3$. For each of them pick colors. You can do that in this many ways:
$$5\cdot 4 + 5\cdot 4 + 5 {4 \choose 3} + 5\cdot 4 + 5\cdot 4 \cdot{3 \choose 2} + {5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 2} + 5{4\choose 2}{2\choose 1} + {5\choose 4} ,
$$
which equals 235.
